# Catch all the ajax call and add spinner when there is ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js

I'm working on a web project where I used backbone.js, now i want to handle all the ajax call globally and add spinner whenever there is a ajax call. 
basically i have to handle all the ajax query in the web project and add spinner when ajax called.

Answer (score 0):

There are various Global Event handlers for this for ajax.
Here have a look : http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/